# Why the middle stroke of the "W"'s letter is very sharp on my codepen?

Tags: html, css

Here the demo: https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/XWrGgyo

here the code:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #082330;
  background-size: .12em 100%;
  font: 16em/1 Arial;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 0.15em;
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: Mansalva;
}

.text--line {
  font-size: .5em;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-copy {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-dasharray: 7% 28%;
  stroke-width: 9px;
  font-family: Mansalva;
  -webkit-animation: stroke-offset 5s infinite linear;
          animation: stroke-offset 5s infinite linear;
}
.text-copy:nth-child(1) {
  stroke: #360745;
  stroke-dashoffset: 7%;
}
.text-copy:nth-child(2) {
  stroke: #D61C59;
  stroke-dashoffset: 14%;
}
.text-copy:nth-child(3) {
  stroke: #E7D84B;
  stroke-dashoffset: 21%;
}
.text-copy:nth-child(4) {
  stroke: #EFEAC5;
  stroke-dashoffset: 28%;
}
.text-copy:nth-child(5) {
  stroke: #1B8798;
  stroke-dashoffset: 35%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes stroke-offset {
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 35%;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 87.5%;
  }
}

@keyframes stroke-offset {
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 35%;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 87.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Mansalva&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1> Hey World </h1>
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 600">
  <symbol id="s-text">
    <text text-anchor="middle"
          x="50%"
          y="35%"
          class="text--line"
          >
      Hey
    </text>
    <text text-anchor="middle"
          x="50%"
          y="68%"
          class="text--line2"
          >
      World
    </text>
    
  </symbol>
  
  <g class="g-ants">
    <use xlink:href="#s-text"
      class="text-copy"></use>     
    <use xlink:href="#s-text"
      class="text-copy"></use>     
    <use xlink:href="#s-text"
      class="text-copy"></use>     
    <use xlink:href="#s-text"
      class="text-copy"></use>     
    <use xlink:href="#s-text"
      class="text-copy"></use>     
  </g>
  
  
</svg>
```

I am wondering why the  middle stroke of the "W"'s letter is very sharp in "Hey World" since it is very smooth in the original font -see the  text.

thanks for any hint

Comment: honestly - it doesn't look sharpened to me.

Comment: @Stender thanks for your feedback Stender, I am talking more specifically about the  middle stroke of the "W"'s letter, what do you think about that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like pointy line join is not noticeable on the font because it is hidden by the font being filled in where your animated outline is not.

If you want to change it though see the [stroke-linejoin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linejoin) attribute.